# SwiftUI - custom TabBar height based on device

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabbar

[image]

I am trying to set up the height of my custom TabBar based on Device, my code:

```
struct MyTabBar: View {
    @Binding var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.index = 0
            }) {
                Image(ImageText.iconHome.image)
            }

            Spacer(minLength: 0)

            Button(action: {
                self.index = 1
            }) {
                Image(ImageText.iconBell.image)
            }

            Spacer(minLength: 0)

            Button(action: {
                self.index = 2
            }) {
                Image(ImageText.iconAdd.image)
            }

            Spacer(minLength: 0)

            Button(action: {
                self.index = 3
            }) {
                Image(ImageText.iconSearch.image).foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }

            Spacer(minLength: 0)

            Button(action: {
                self.index = 4
            }) {
                Image(ImageText.iconHamburger.image)
            }

        }.padding(.horizontal, 26).frame(height: 56)
    }
}
```

If the devices have notch, how can I set my custom TabBar to have higher height? Does SwiftUI have something that can be useful here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `GeometryReader` element to access the safe area insets, and add it as a padding using `.safeAreaInsets.bottom` (note that the Xcode autocompletion is almost never working on `GeometryProxy` properties):

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            // Content goes here
            Spacer()

            // Custom tab bar
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    .padding()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    .padding()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    .padding()
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    .padding()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.bottom, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            .background(Color.red)

        }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
}
```